LIveCharts and Series Alignment
Alignment incorrect
So I have two CartesianChart Controls that have to have the Series in each synced up. I am not able to get them to align to the right so they both align the content of the series in each.
The trends need to be right justified. How can I do this? Not much documentation on this stuff in the docs online.
Thanks in advance.
Not sure what to do.
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="MainChart" 
   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
   Series="{Binding Series}"
   XAxes="{Binding ScrollableAxes}"
   YAxes ="{Binding YAxes}"
   ZoomMode="X" 
   DrawMargin="{Binding Margin}"
   BorderBrush="Blue"
   BorderThickness="2"
   Dp:MouseBehaviour.MouseWheelCommand="{Binding MouseWheelCmd}"
   PointerPressedCommand="{Binding Path=PointerDownCommandStoc }"
   PointerMoveCommand="{Binding Path=PointerMoveCommandStoc }"  
   PointerReleasedCommand="{Binding Path=PointerUpCommandStoc}"
   DrawMarginFrame="{Binding DrawMarginFrame}"
   UpdateStartedCommand="{Binding ChartUpdatedCommand}">
</lvc:CartesianChart>
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="MyStochasticChart"  Margin="95,0,0,0"
   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainChart}"  
   Height="120"
   AutoUpdateEnabled="True" 
   LegendPosition="Hidden"
   LegendTextSize="16"
   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
   Series="{Binding SeriesStochastics}" 
   XAxes="{Binding XAxesStoc}"
   YAxes="{Binding YAxesStoc}"
   LegendBackgroundPaint="{Binding LedgendBackgroundPaint}"
   LegendTextPaint="{Binding LegendTextPaint}"
   DrawMarginFrame="{Binding DrawMarginFrame}"/>`

